# UML Modelling in C++Builder 2010 Professional

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-2010

I'd like to do some basic class diagram UML models in the Pro version of C++Builder 2010. Embarcadero has a [C++Builder Features Matrix](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/cbuilder/cbuilder-feature-matrix.pdf) document, one line of which says "UML Code Visualization – at any time, get a UML model view of your source code" and has a check in the "Professional" column of that table -- I assume this means it should be available to me.

Yet, when I open an existing project and do a View | Model View, there's nothing in the Model View window. The only diagram I can find is on the Graph tab of the C++ Class Explorer. I wouldn't call that a UML diagram myself -- is that what Embarcadero is referring to?

Edit: I found out that Pro does indeed have Modelling support; somehow it had been turned off on the project I had open. I added another project to the project group and then the IDE offered to turn on Modelling support when I clicked the Model View tab. I was then able to add a Class Diagram to that project, though I'm still looking for a way to import the project's existing objects onto the diagram.

Answer (score 0):

When I clicked it on my project it said converting for a bit then showed me a tree of my objects...  If this is what they were advertising I dont really consider this UML...